# Function defined on an interval $(a, \infty)$ having argument equal to $a$

Tags: functions, limsup-and-liminf

In the definition for limit superior of real functions on this [page](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-limit-superior-and-limit-inferior-of-functions-of-real-n) we have:

Let $f : (a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. The limit superior as $x \to \infty$ is defined as $\displaystyle{\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sup_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} = \inf_{x \geq a} \left \{ \sup_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} \right \}}$

I am wondering if the last equality is wrong, namely $\displaystyle{\inf_{x \geq a} \left \{ \sup_{t \geq x} \{ f(t) \} \right \}}$, if the function is defined on an interval $(a, \infty)$ shouldn't it be $\displaystyle{\inf_{x > a}}$ instead of $\displaystyle{\inf_{x \geq a}}$?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ isn't defined at $a$ one of the inequalities must be strict. $x \geqslant a$ and $t > x$ would also work. But it's a very minor glitch.

Comment: Well I asked because it is repeated for all the other definitions on the page so I thought it might be intentional.